# Is there a way to send push notification from a web portal to Google Cloud Messaging?

Tags: c#, android

I am trying to research on a way to send push notifications from a web portal to Google Cloud Messaging. So, basically I would like to write a service in c# which would allow me pass parameters such as (payload and recipient) and the service would send the message to GCM. The GCM would then sync the data back to my users who have my app on the smartphone. Any help or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just send the parameters to GCM directly. Why do you need an intermediary service?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link which explains how can you send push notification from web portals to device.

[Sending Push Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-gcm-get-started)

May be it's not exactly how you wanted it but can give you a good idea about how it works!